# Securing a 'pass through' web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, security

I am currently assigned to a project which involves implementing a back-end for an app which will be developed at a later stage. The app will request sensitive (personal) information from another platform in the first (prototype) version (available per SOAP service). We will add more platforms in the future. So the following idea came up:

```
APP <---> NEW WEB SERVICE <---> SOAP SERVICE (with the actual data)
```

We are placing the new webservice between the app and the SOAP service because the SOAP service is built by an external party (not really cooperating). Also because of the following situation which may occur, in the event that we will have more sources to supply the data:

```
APP <---> NEW WEB SERVICE <---> SOAP SERVICE (with the actual data)
                          <---> WEB SERVICE #2
                          <---> WEB SERVICE #3
```

Since a web enviroment where a user can log-in already exists and our manager wants to have one account for the app and the web enviroment, the authentication for users should ALWAYS be done by the SOAP service. This complicates the aspect of authentication and security in the new web service.

The question arises if this would mean that the 'new web service' is nothing more then a 'pass through' or 'forward' service? But how should I secure this 'new web service'? **Authentication and sesions should be handled by the existing SOAP service.**

If the 'new web service' supplies the authentication and such, solutions like: Oauth or ASP.NET Identity.  I have conducted research towards these options and concluded they don't apply in this context.

**My question is: How do I get the most out of the available security options for this new (forwarding) web service? If I even should add an extra layer of security or not.**

I came up with the following, not sure if this would be the right approach:

- Using TLS, version 1.2 (obviously);
- Create an api key and secret for every user;
- Encrypt user-login details (username, password) with an asymmetric encryption algorithm.

Comment: These two requirements sound contradictionary: have authentication in the new service and maintain the authentication in the soap service. It is not clear then what are you asking for. Are you asking for an idea to workaround this contradiction? Or rather, you know how to workaround it and you merely ask for authentication options for web services?

Comment: The two authentications 'types' is not an requirement, I am just wondering if this would be a good approach on handeling this kind of project. The only requirement is to authenticate with SOAP, the other authentication with the new service is just an idea I had. I am basically asking what other people would do in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is **NO**. Doing a user level validation from a web service can slow down your whole system and more importantly it does not add any value. Instead of doing that, what you need to do is make sure that the Web Service is secured and cannot be accessed by unauthorised parties. To achieve that, you can use Certifications, WSS, SSL, firewalls etc.

Let's assume this webservice is used in a school to publish exam results. So obviously students should not be able to access it. So you have to control that at your application level, not at the web service level. You can of cause allow students to send a message to the WS and then get a response from the WS saying "You are not authorised to do this". But it will consume your resources unnecessarily. It will also slow down your system.

The 2nd scenario that you have mentioned is valid. It's good practice to have a middle layer, so that you can cater to multiple versions of the external web service, without changing your core application. If the external application is not very reliable, you can also handle reliability issues gracefully using this middle layer. For an example, suppose the external service is used for `ledger posting`. Which means your application will post any given transaction only once. What do you do if it fails? You can have a retry mechanism in your middle layer. So likewise a middle layer can actually add more value to your system if it's designed carefully.

Comment: Could you explain what you have in mind for certifications? I am looking into certificates, but not sure how this would work later for app implementations in iOS or Android. Client certificates shouldn't be static, as it is considered to be insecure? Thanks!

Comment: very well explained